# [Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occurred]

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-signin, react-native-firebase

This Error Occurred while Trying to Signin with Google using Firebase in React Native.

1. I have added Support Email on Firebase Project Setting.
2. Also Added The SHA-1 Key Which was generated by
   '''./gradlew signingReport''' to the project.
3. Also the WebClientId is added which I got from the client-id in oauth_client in google-services.json.

can anybody Help ??????